# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid page request. when get page info of pdf

Tags: typescript, pdf.js

I am trying to zoom in and zoom out of the pdf using pdf.js, this is the function to render and rerender the pdf:

```
const renderPdfPage = async (pdf: any, pdfJS: any, pageNum: number) => {
        if (!canvasRef || !canvasRef.current) return;
        const docCavas = document.getElementById("the-canvas" + pageNum);
        if (!docCavas) {
            const el = window.document.createElement("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
            el.id = "the-canvas" + pageNum;
            canvasRef.current.append(el);
        }
        if(pageNum > pdf.numPages){
            return;
        }
        const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum);
        const viewport = page.getViewport({
            scale: pdfScale
        });
        let canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas' + pageNum) as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
        const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            const textContent = page.getTextContent();
            return textContent;
        }).then(function (textContent: string) {
            const textLayer = document.querySelector(`.${styles.textLayer}`) as HTMLDivElement;
            if (!textLayer) return;
            textLayer.style.left = canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
            textLayer.style.top = canvas.offsetTop + 'px';
            textLayer.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
            textLayer.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
            textLayer.style.setProperty('--scale-factor', pdfScale.toString());
            pdfJS.renderTextLayer({
                textContentSource: textContent,
                container: textLayer,
                viewport: viewport,
                textDivs: []
            });
        });
    }
```

Now I facing a issue that sometimes the get pdf page will failed and shows error like this:

```
api.js:2917 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid page request.
    at WorkerTransport.getPage (api.js:2917:29)
    at PDFDocumentProxy.getPage (api.js:837:28)
    at renderPdfPage (Previewer.tsx:55:32)
    at getPage (Previewer.tsx:136:68)
```

the error was throw from this line `const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum);`, I have recheck my code and did not figure out why this would happen. Am I missing something? waht should I do to fixed this issue? this is the zoom function:

```
const handleZoomOut = async (pdfUrl: any) => {
        if (!pdfUrl) {
            return;
        }
        var zoomoutbutton = document.getElementById("zoomoutbutton") as HTMLButtonElement;
        zoomoutbutton.onclick = function () {
            if (pdfScale <= 0.25) {
                return;
            }
            setPdfScale(pdfScale - 0.25);
            displayPage(currentPdf, pageNum);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when the `pageNum` value I passed was of type string rather than integer.

Comment: I ran into this when `i = 0` haha, I guess `i = 1` to start.